# Using Git from client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, git

I wonder if there is a js library of some sort dedicated to working with Git. Particulary I'm interested in the following js-git interface:

1. client changes text in his browser on some form
2. client-side javascript wraps it in a "commit" form
3. client-side js send commit to remote private git server.

I guess I can give it a different spin:

1. client changes text in his browser.
2. sends changes to remote server (e.g. Node.js)
3. Node.js bundles the changes to "a commit" form and sends it to git server.

Are there modern javascript libraries for this kind of things?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[jsgit](https://github.com/creationix/js-git) seems to be the most widely used implementation.

BTW I would suggest having a backend (node.js + Express e.g.) that talks with the git repository.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can make `git` changes from js, but you can definitely do the following:

1. Create a diff in the browser using [google/diff-match-patch](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch) js implementation
2. Submit this diff to remote server
3. Process the diff on the server into git by doing [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply)

`git apply from-browser.patch`

Note: I'm not a 100% sure that the formats would be compatible out of the box, so that's something you'd need to check.